# Large queries to blockchain

Tags: solidity

If we stored an array of millions of objects in the blockchain and then added a getter and kept requesting the data wouldn't that overload the blockchain? Or the node that we're connecting to?

These queries don't require Gas so I'm wondering what stops this from happening? Why don't getter functions need gas? They may be doing some complicated logic still or returning a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

Querying objects does not cost any gas because you have to query them from a node. Usually, you will run your own node (thereby incurring costs yourself) or you can use a third party service like etherscan.io or infura.io. These services work based on API calls and as such, they also impose limits (because if they didn't, it would be possible to flood them with requests).

For example: [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/apis) has a request limit of 5 API calls per second.

> The Etherscan Ethereum Developer APIs are provided as a community
>   service and without warranty, so please just use what you need and no
>   more. They support both GET/POST requests and a rate limit of 5
>   requests/sec (exceed and you will be blocked).